# I still don't know what I am. I have no Brain!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I have no eyes yet I see.
>
> I have no mouth yet I speak.
>
> I have no hears yet I hear.
>
> I have learned everything I know.
>
> I always know the way.
>
> You cannot control me!
>
> I think someone took my wheel but luckily I have spares.

What am I?

Comment: If someone else messes up on their interpretation of the last clue I will give a hint.

Comment: Also is your spelling error intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A self driving car?

I have no eyes yet I see.

> Cameras allow the car to see

I have no mouth yet I speak.

> Speakers on the car can play music

I have no hears yet I hear.

> Maybe it is voice enabled, and can take verbal commands through a mic?

I have learned everything I know.

> The self driving car is driven by an AI. Neural nets are trained over long periods of time with lots of data to get them to be reliable. They 'learn' everything this way.

I always know the way.

> It can drive you to your destination

You cannot control me!

> Well, it is self driving, isn't it?

I think someone took my wheel but luckily I have spares.

> Cars usually have a spare wheel.

Comment: Yes You got it right. However the last clue is about how they took away the steering wheel(it is self driving) but it still has tire wheel(because it is a car),

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a

> GPS?

I have no eyes yet I see.
I have no mouth yet I speak.
I have no hears (ears?) yet I hear.

> A GPS is a machine but it knows the position of the car, can give vocal instructions, and can respond to spoken commands.

I have learned everything I know.

> A GPS comes with all its maps pre-installed; it does not learn the layout of roads as you drive.

I always know the way.

> One would hope that their GPS never gets lost...

You cannot control me!

> A GPS will always display what it chooses as the best route.

I think someone took my wheels but luckily I have spares.

> Not entirely sure...Maybe when the driver controlling the wheels misses an instruction, the GPS can set a new path?

Comment: Ah so close :).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Would you happen to be:

> A book?

I have no eyes yet I see.

> You can visualize what the author has written; plus you could have a creature with no eyes and the capability to see.

I have no mouth yet I speak.

> When reading books containing characters we are familiar with, we can often hear certain character's voices, and the sounds of the waves crashing against the rocks.

I have no ears yet I hear.

> Authors will often take feedback into consideration prior to writing a sequel; and yet this is another what about this *grimmock* creature thing?

I have learned everything I know.

> The author has crafted the story from either fiction he/she created, or fact which he/she learned.

I always know the way.

> Haven't you ever watched *The Pagemaster*? Adventure always knows the way; plus, who wouldn't follow Captain Nemo?

You cannot control me!

> No matter how hard you try, 90% of books have a predetermined fate.

I think someone took my wheel but luckily I have spares.

> You thought ahead!

Comment: Ah sorry no. But I do like your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

> Maps..

Precisely..

> **Google Maps**... The smartest and the best out there..

- I have no eyes yet I see.

  > It doesn't really SEE where you are.. instead senses it using location services. Doesn't SEE the traffic ahead, uses crowdsourcing to KNOW the traffic ahead.. [Check this out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Traffic)
- I have no mouth yet I speak.

  > Google Maps sure does tell you using its voice where to go next..
- I have no hears yet I hear.

  > **OK Google!** and tell where you need to go. Just do this and Google maps readily listens to you and is ready with directions.
- I have learned everything I know.

  - > Everything I know ==> The offline maps;
  - > I have learned ==> Downloaded
  - > So... the parts of the map which I know(offline) are the ones which are downloaded(learnt).
- I always know the way.

  > Just tell where you need to go. The directions to your destination are ready in an instant.
- You cannot control me!

  > Google always chooses the best route for you, regardless of what you're expecting.
- I think someone took my wheel but luckily I have spares.

  > Go wherever you want to, irrespective of what way is shown. It always reroutes showing you the route to your destination.

Comment: Ooh I like your thoughts. But I think people keep messing up on the last one.

Answer (score -1):

> Your brain.... It technically fits the answer.

Comment: "I think someone took my wheel but luckily I have spares." - almost but no dice.

Comment: Title: "I have no brain" :P

Comment: Heya, thanks for the answer! Would you mind adding an explanation as to how this answer fits each line of the riddle? Thanks!